# Extends broadleaf default admin controller

Tags: java, spring, broadleaf-commerce

I want to create my own controller for admin side (broadleaf framework), which extends AdminBasicEntityController.
 There is my controller code:

```
    public class AdminArticleController extends AdminBasicEntityController {

    @Autowired
    private ArticleService articleService;

    @Override
    public String addEntity(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model, @PathVariable Map<String, String> pathVars, @ModelAttribute("entityForm") EntityForm entityForm, BindingResult result) throws Exception {
        return super.addEntity(request, response, model, pathVars, entityForm, result);
    }

    @Override
    public String saveEntityJson(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model, @PathVariable Map<String, String> pathVars, @PathVariable("id") String id, @ModelAttribute("entityForm") EntityForm entityForm, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes ra) throws Exception {
        return super.saveEntityJson(request, response, model, pathVars, id, entityForm, result, ra);
//        articleService.updateArticleEntity();
    }
}
```

I also added the next code to AdminServletConfig file:

```
@Bean
public AdminBasicEntityController adminBasicEntityController() {
    return new AdminArticleController();
}
```

And i have the problem:
 My stacktrace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminControllerHandlerMapping' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/ntsarkevich/.m2/repository/org/broadleafcommerce/broadleaf-open-admin-platform/6.0.1-GA/broadleaf-open-admin-platform-6.0.1-GA.jar!/org/broadleafcommerce/openadmin/web/controller/AdminControllerHandlerMapping.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'adminBasicEntityController' method 
public java.lang.String org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.web.controller.entity.AdminBasicEntityController.addEntity(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,org.springframework.ui.Model,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.web.form.entity.EntityForm,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult) throws java.lang.Exception
to {[/{sectionKey:.+}/add],methods=[POST]}: There is already 'blAdminBasicEntityController' bean method
public java.lang.String org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.web.controller.entity.AdminBasicEntityController.addEntity(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,org.springframework.ui.Model,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.web.form.entity.EntityForm,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult) throws java.lang.Exception mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.community.admin.AdminApplication.main(AdminApplication.java:12) [classes/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'adminBasicEntityController' method 
public java.lang.String org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.web.controller.entity.AdminBasicEntityController.addEntity(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,org.springframework.ui.Model,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.web.form.entity.EntityForm,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult) throws java.lang.Exception
to {[/{sectionKey:.+}/add],methods=[POST]}: There is already 'blAdminBasicEntityController' bean method
public java.lang.String org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.web.controller.entity.AdminBasicEntityController.addEntity(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,org.springframework.ui.Model,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.web.form.entity.EntityForm,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult) throws java.lang.Exception mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.assertUniqueMethodMapping(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:580) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:544) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:265) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lambda$detectHandlerMethods$1(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:250) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:248) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:218) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:188) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:136) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 16 more
```

What's wrong with my controller. I see the guide on [guide](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/admin/admin-controllers)

**UPDATE**
If I add `@RequestMapping({"/admin/pages"})` to class level my controller methods are ignored, and the same parent class methods work. Why?

Many thanks!

Comment: It seems like you're wanting to override the functionality of saving either a custom entity (Article) or possibly all of your products are articles. For the former you would instead want to simply add an `@RequestMapping` to the class level with the exact url that's used when saving your entity and **do not** override `blAdminBasicEntityController`. What you have in your question would work since you've created a new, more specific mapping. For the latter you'll want to extend `AdminProductController` and override the `blAdminProductController` like @mouse_8b suggested.

Comment: @pequals Yes, I want to override the functionality: save my additional entity and use  AdminBasicEntityController save method. So, thank you for advice - it resolved the problem, but my controllers' methods are never used

Comment: @pequals, my parent controller always catch the request and parent method is called

Comment: Looking at `AdminProductController` it looks like your override method in the child class has to have the `@RequestMapping` of the parent methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close! To override an existing Broadleaf bean, be sure to use the bean name declared in the annotation. Name your bean "blAdminBasicEntityController" like this:

```
@Bean
public AdminBasicEntityController blAdminBasicEntityController() {
    return new AdminArticleController();
}
```

The error you are seeing is due to there being two beans with the same mapping. This is is happening because AdminBasicEntityController is annotated with `@Controller("blAdminBasicEntityController")`, which means it will get picked up by component scanning and create a bean named `blAdminBasicEntityController`. Since AdminArticleController extends AdminBasicEntityController, once the AdminArticleController bean is created, there would be 2 mappings for every mapping in AdminBasicEntityController. The solution is to override the Broadleaf bean instead of adding an additional one.

Comment: thank you, it helps resolve the problem, but my controller method is never used. I checked it via debug. Only the parent controller method is used and I can not understand why.

Comment: So,  I change parent class to AdminPageController. For AdminBasicEntityController the getSectionKey() method must be realized or copied to child controller.